# Php different timezones

Tags: php, mysql, time, timezone

I'm developing a web app in php mysql which should be usable in the whole world. 
In this app there is a big usage of time so I'm wondering if there
is any work to do on the timezones differences or if php is automatically recognizing the different timezones before saving in the db ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697304/php-mysql-timezone-clarification?rq=1

Comment: Provide a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL Server Time Zone Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html)

And ensure that you store all dates and times in the database in UTC. It's the only way to remain sane.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function for geting time zone for differenct places

```
function getDatetimeNow() {

$tz_object = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Karachi');
//date_default_timezone_set('Brazil/East');
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime->setTimezone($tz_object);
return $datetime->format('Y\-m\-d\ h:i:s');
```

}

for differnect time zone location find it on below link

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php