# Symfony multi timezone app

Tags: php, web, timezone, symfony

I'm developing a web app using Symfony3 and would like to spread it around the world. But I'm wondering how it works concerning the different timezones management.

I'm looking for an answer to this question on the web and made plenty of tests since a few days. None of them worked.

Does someone have a magic solution to that?

## UPDATE

I've learned about helpers like camroncade. But this is just converting the php times.
I'd like to be able to convert the times directly in the SQL

I'm saving all the timestamps in UTC in my db.

I had two ideas for that, but both didn't work :

1st: Creating a stored function convert_tz(timestamp, from, to) and call it in all my SQL queries when I want to save or display a timestamp.
But this is not possible with Symfony.

2nd: Telling to mysql what timezone the user's session corresponds to and mysql would automatically convert to the right time. People told me that mysql would can do that, but I don't find any way on how telling this to mysql from Symfony.

Comment: Two months ago you've posted the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247777/php-different-timezones) (closed as too broad). Maybe you could improve this a bit, adding more specific info (and your code if necessary) about the context related to the problem you are facing... don't you think?

Comment: Post some code - no help unless you post some code...

Comment: I added some additionnal explanations

Answer (score 1):

I think they are wrong saying that Timezone should only be set for displaying purposes. It is important to operate on certain timezones to avoid problems with DST changes.

Example:

```
    $date1 = new DateTime('2019-08-05 18:00:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'));
    $date2 = new DateTime('2019-08-05 18:00:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'));

    var_dump($date1);
    var_dump($date2);

    $date2->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

    $date1->modify('+5 months');
    $date2->modify('+5 months');

    $date2->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'));

    var_dump($date1);
    var_dump($date2);
```

Initial dates are equal. Then one of them is converted to UTC and the same operation is performed on both dates. At the end the date is converted back to Europe/Warsaw and you realize that `$date2` is now 1 hour behind `$date1`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be more of a Doctrine/Database issue. Check [Working With DateTime Instances](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html) from the Doctrine project.

> **Handling different Timezones with the DateTime Type**
>
> If you first come across the requirement to save different timezones
>   you may be still optimistic about how to manage this mess, however **let
>   me crush your expectations fast**. There is not a single database out
>   there (supported by Doctrine 2) that supports timezones correctly
>
> [...]
>
> However there is a **workaround** that even allows correct date-time
>   handling with timezones:
>
> - Always convert any DateTime instance to UTC.
> - Only set Timezones for displaying purposes
> - Save the Timezone in the Entity for persistence.

So it's possible but not that straight forward.

In one of our app we send emails and push notifications to users in different timezones at specific times. We always take into account the user's timezone when doing queries in the DB.

Comment: "Only set Timezones for displaying purposes" - it's not true, what if business logic require from you to set the date to the last minute in current month for specific country? You can't do this in UTC.